the preLaunchTask 'C/C++:g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1
Изучаю C++. Имеются три файла main.cpp, square.cpp, square.hpp и запускаться они не хотят. Использую VisualStudioCode
Ошибка: the preLaunchTask 'C/C++:g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1
main.cpp
#include "square.hpp"

int main() {

    square(5);
    
    return 0;
}

square.cpp
int square(int x) 
{
    return x*x
}

square.hpp
#ifndef SQUARE_HPP
#define SQUARE_HPP

int square(int x);

#endif

MinGW установил, зависимость в системе тоже. Другой код(пример ниже будет) запускается без ошибок.
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout <<"anything";
    return 0;
}

В многих гайдах сказано удалять папку .vscode перед запуском но это не помогает.
в файле tasks.json лежит вот это:
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

Прошу помощи, прошерстил уже все что можно было и ничего не помогло!

Стоило бы открыть лог сборки, выполненной в preLaunchTask и исправить указанные там ошибки.

Отрыл лог, написано что ошибок нету.

Приводите в вопросе лог выполнения команды в task. Чтобы там не было ошибок, но в конце было terminated with exit code -1.

square.cpp это отдельная единица трансляции, скорее всего ошибка линкера, что не смог найти определение функции.
